# NeoVim Error492 "Not a Plugin Command: PlugInstall"

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I'm tying to use "vim-plug" and run and I have already installed the plug-in to ~Local\nvim\site\autoload and it gives me this the error every time I try to run the program.

```
call plug#begin('~/.local/nvim/site/autoload/plug.vim')

Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plug 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plug 'rafi/awesome-vim-colorschemes'
Plug 'preservim/nerdcommenter'
Plug 'ervandew/supertab'

call plug#end()
```

Comment: where is your `init.vim`?